# Is the magnetic field related directly to the Pauli exclusion principle?

Tags: magnetic-fields, quantum-spin, pauli-exclusion-principle

The fact that the spin is a quantity related to the magnetic field, is it a consequence of the Pauli exclusion principle or vice versa?

Comment: Classical electrodynamics includes a magnetic field.

Comment: perhaps helpful https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/738376/46708  https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/745204/46708

Answer (score 2):

The Pauli exclusion principle belongs to the realm of quantum mechanics.

The magnetic field is in the realm of classical electrodynamics.

Mainstream theory accepts that the underlying level for all theories of physics is quantum mechanical. Electromagnetic interactions at the quantum level are between charged particles with the exchange of photons, virtual ones in quantum field theory with calculations given Feynman diagrams . At this level, [the macroscopic electric and magnetic fields are calculated to appear through a plethora of organized virtual photons.](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/231240/how-virtual-photons-give-rise-to-electric-and-or-magnetic-field).

The Pauli exclusion principle applies on spin 1/2 particles. The photon , whether virtual or not, has spin 1. Thus The electric and magnetic fields can  not be related to the Pauli exclusion principle.